# python calling shell command (open) and waiting for command finish. How to get a signal once the job has finished?

Tags: python, shell

I'm using an app called shoebox.app with can split a psd file to several png files.
The app provides a CMD interface and I tried it in termial which works fine:

```
open /Applications/ShoeBox.app --args \"files=xxx.psd\"
```

and now I want to write a python script to do the work:

```
import os
if __name__ == '__main__':
    CMD = "open /Applications/ShoeBox.app --args \"files=xxx.psd\""
    os.system(CMD)
```

this also works fine.

Now what I want to do something **after** the "spliting psd to png job" finishes:

```
import os
if __name__ == '__main__':
    CMD = "open /Applications/ShoeBox.app --args \"files=xxx.psd\""
    os.system(CMD)

    do_something_to_pngs_func()
```

The problem is the "split job" takes several seconds and I need to wait till it ends and then call my
`do_something_to_pngs_func` function.

**But, how could I know the `os.system(CMD)` actually ends?**

Now my interim solution is to add a "`time.sleep(10)`" before calling my function, but that's not the best solution, of course.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `open` command returns immediately. To make `open` wait for the completion of the application, use the `-W` and `-n` switches:

```
CMD = "open -W -n /Applications/ShoeBox.app --args \"files=xxx.psd\""
```

Reference:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html